# Generic class as base causes XAML error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the classes `customer` and `product`. Their similarities are in the class `Base Record`. However, the types in `Base Record` always depend on whether it is a `customer` or `product`. Therefore, I have `Base Record` created generically.

As soon as `customer` or `product` inherits from `Base Record` , I get XMAL-error in my WPF project. Unfortunately, I do not know why this is, why I write here ;)

Header of BaseRecord:

```
public abstract class BaseRecord<T> : Notify where T : class, new()
```

Header of Customer:

```
public class Customer : BaseRecord<Data_Layer.Customer>
```

XAML error:

```
   Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Version=1.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
   because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on 
   demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'
```

AND:

```
The tag 'CustomerAddWindow' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Business_Layer.Windows.Customer;assembly=Business_Layer'
```

If I make the class `BaseRecord` not generic everything works as I want.

in XAML, I instantiate

```
<local:Customer x:Key="CustomerViewModel "/>
```

Happy new year.

Comment: Does customer inherit from Window or is it a non-wpf class?

Comment: @Luis Filipe it is in a non-wpf class. My Business_Layer is a 'Class Library' project

Answer (score 1):

**XAML does not support generics directly.**

There are some side projects that aim in solving this issue but i always chose to live with it. It really never hindered my application architecture.

A workaround which i believe it's simple and effective is to have a mid-inheritance class which solves the generic.

For instance,

```
public abstract class BaseRecord<T> : Notify where T : class, new()

public abstract class CustomerBase : BaseRecord<Data_Layer.Customer>

public class Customer : CustomerBase
```

---

I currently develop a WPF application and i do not need any generics in my XAMLs.

I have zero code in the xaml code-behind. Truly, my base window class has code behind all UI-related due to some customizations.

If you follow the `MVVM` architecture that generic, which is likely to be a property in your base window should, most likely, belong in the ViewModel class.

Comment: I have followed your advice but it doesn't work. I get the same errors like in my post...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error and want to show my solution for it:

I have added the reference to my WPF-Project where my classes are which I use in the generic one.

My architecture is:

Business_Layer for business logic

Data_Layer to maintain my data from DB

Presentation_Layer as View.

I didn't reference the Data_Layer to the Presentation_Layer because there was no need. But when you are using a generic class inside WPF-project you have to that WPF can resolve it.

That was the first error want to tell:

```
 Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Version=1.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'
```

I don't know why but after adding this data_layer reference to presentation_layer, I don't need the workaround class. I can use

```
public class CustomerBase : BaseRecord<Data_Layer.Customer>
```

directly without any errors.