# Partial declarations of 'MainWindow' must not specify different base classes with Generic Base Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my main window, i currently have

```
public partial class MainWindow : WpfView<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and in my XAML file, i have

```
<Window x:Class="wpfMvvm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfMvvm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

I am aware that `<Window></Window>` needs to be changed to WpfView or some form of that, but i have not found a single exampel of this on SO or google.

Does anybody know what the base tag would be in the XAML file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic class as base causes XAML error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703216/generic-class-as-base-causes-xaml-error)

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer on google:

```
<local:WpfView x:Class="wpfMvvm.MainWindow"
           x:TypeArguments="local:MainWindowViewModel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfMvvm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</local:WpfView>
```

uses `local:WpfView` as the base tag, and then adds the `x:TypeArguments="local:MainWindowViewModel"` attribute. Works exactly as required.

Answer (score -1):

Your base class specified in Xaml is `Window`.

Your base class specified in the cs file is `WpfView<MainWindowViewModel>`.

The base class types need to match.

You can solve that by creating a non generic base class and using it in both files:

```
   public class NonGenericWindow :  WpfView<MainWindowViewModel>
   {
   }
```

Comment: I know they need to match, this was stated in the question, the point of using generics is to avoid having to do all of this. If i was going to use `NonGenericWindow` i wouldnt have created WpfView in the first place

Comment: what's the problem with creating a non generic derived class?